# No route matches [GET] sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've made authorization following this tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#cha-sign_in_sign_out but now I want to add subdomains to my application.

I've added this to my `routes.rb`:

```
match '/' => 'students/board', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'student' }, via: 'get'
```

If I want to redirect user after sign in to his subdomain like this:

```
redirect_to :subdomain => 'student', :path => '/'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/sessions"
```

If I redirect user without a subdomain he is normally redirected. I don't understand why it's trying to get 'sessions' path. I would be grateful for some suggestions. I didn't find anything online which is related to login sessions and subdomains.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sessions route somewhere defined?

Comment: @Deekor, No, it's not needed. If I don't put `:subdomain => 'student'` everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something in your code you aren't showing us redirecting you to the sessions path.

Have you tried naming the path then redirecting there?

**routes.rb:**

```
get '/' => 'students/board', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'student' }, as: 'student_login'
```

then use:

```
redirect_to student_login_path
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have nothing different than in that tutorial. I just c/p everything. This signs in user normally but doesn't show subdomain.